# Intellij diff of images

Tags: git, image, intellij-idea, intellij-plugin

In my git repository live several images. Sometimes I need to change one and if I want to commit it Intellij shows me in the diff view two files. Left side the image from the repository right my local changed image. Most times this works great, but currently I need something which really makes a diff between both images. If one pixel changes I need to see it. With current approach this is (practically) not possible.

How do I do it with intellij? Or where could I start for writing a pluging to achieve my goal?

Comment: If the functionality you use is in the community edition, the source is available

Comment: That's a good hint. Its easy to write plugins, but you need to know where to hook in. And this I do not know yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally, I build my own plugin "imgdiff". If Jetbrains approves it can be used https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/12691-image-diff It works very simple hopefully it will be useful for someone.

Comment: I love this one! Its perfect for golden file testing.

Answer (score 1):

> How do I do it with IntelliJ

Using [External Diff](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/settings-tools-external-diff-tools.html), or with some plugin.

IntelliJ Diff can show images but cannot highlight changes in images, as it is not designed to compare binaries.

Here is the request to add image comparing tool https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-99316

> Or where could I start for writing a pluging to achieve my goal?

Here is the [code on GitHub](https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community)

Here are some [docs on the plugin development](https://www.jetbrains.org/intellij/sdk/docs/welcome.html)

Comment: I like the idea. Unfortunately the "diff" is not clickable under https://www.jetbrains.org/intellij/sdk/docs/reference_guide/vcs_integration_for_plugins.html And do you know how I could hook into the "diff" view to provide a third viewer? Currently there are "Side-by-side viewer" and "unified-viewer" I would "image-viewer" to be found there.